# Can someone load and run malicious code into/from css?

Tags: css, security

Can someone load and run malicious codes into and from a css file? I just want to know if it is possible to load malicious code from a css file `(example.css)`.

Are there any codes that can be placed in the css file that are malicious? for example javascript or php files can be very dangerous if we put a malicious code into them. Like PHP can query database, javascript can load other stuff. Now what about CSS?

I am just curious if it is possible to cause security problems using css file too.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please see: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37832/css-based-attacks

Answer (score 0):

Well we can set the src property of images from CSS. The src property usually contains the url of the image, but it can also contain the image itself in base64 encoded format.

It is possible to write malicious javascript or php code and then encode it using base64 authentication and use it in the src attribute of an image